# discord.py missing category api and enum def

Tags: python, categories, discord, discord.py, channel

Good evening,
i've decided to create a discord bot using python, alongside with their python API, discord.py, everything works as expected but i got to a point where i want to add a voice channel to a category channel and i found out that the api docs is barely specifying anything about them (about manipulating category channels).

On the Discord.py latest documentation page at the channelType which "Specifies the type of Channel." there is the "category" type but in the python code there isnt (running 0.16.12) (see photos)

[the python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUSXI.png)
[discord.py channelType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7DHf.png) (and this is the only place that a category is specified)

I'm not completely sure what is going on, i've done some searches and i couldn't find anything related to manipulating categories with the python API.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please put your code in the question rather than linking to an image?

Comment: Just to clarify: discord.py isn't the "Python API" of Discord. It's a Python wrapper for the Discord API, that is, a library which will allow you to interact with the Discord API, which is unique. Also discord.py wasn't created and isn't maintained by Discord, but by individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) version `0.16.12` [was released on 1 October 2017](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/0.16.12/).  The [commit that added `ChannelType.category`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/e4cafb5057cac064db1dee0e86fe56dced1c74f6)  (and updated the documentation) was made on 28 November 2017.  No official release has been made with that change (of the async branch, the rewrite branch has it).